# Pybluez and Gattlib error

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to run a script that is using pybluez library for Ble, but when I'm running the script I got this error:

```
    from gattlib import *
    ImportError:  No module named gattlib
```

So I tried to install the gattlib as super user with the command:

```
sudo pip install gattlib
```

on my Raspberry but I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error:command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

(O.S Raspbian running on Raspberry Pi 3)

Script:

```
    # bluetooth low energy scan
      from bluetooth.ble import DiscoveryService

      service = DiscoveryService()
      devices = service.discover(2)

      for address, name in devices.items():
          print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: For Python 3, tried everything. This finally worked for me: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55530/pybluez-and-gattlib-error

Answer (score 5):

Thats because one of the dependencies is missing. Its also better that u download it and compile it from source. install mercurial

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

the clone the source of gattlib

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib
cd pygattlib
cat DEPENDS
```

you need to install all those dependencies, the reason you getting that error is because you didn't install libboost-thread-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev
```

now install gattlib like any other python module.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

That should fix it. Thats how I install it on the RPi 3

Comment: This does not appear to work with Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi 3, and I had to do some extra steps, so I'll expand over @michael-jalloh answer:

1. Install Mercurial

   `sudo apt-get install mercurial`
2. Then, clone gattlib's source:

   `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib
   cd pygattlib
   cat DEPENDS`
3. Then install glib-2.0:

   `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`
4. Then install boost:

   `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`
5. At this point will still fail because it's looking for `libboost_python-py34`, and a newer version is installed `libboost_python-py35`, so you need to run:

   `sudo ln -s /dir/to/libboost/libboost_python-py35.so /dir/to/libboost/libboost_python-py34.so`

   In my device the `/dir/to/libboost` is `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`
6. Now you can install gattlib

   `sudo python setup.py install`

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

This post worked for me. The key is to change the dependency to 36 version of the library.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463847/got-error-while-download-gattlib-via-pip3/52271293#52271293