# Installing Gattlib error

Tags: python, bluetooth

Like many others, I've had problems installing `gattlib` using pip.

I've followed the steps outline in this question to no avail:

[Pybluez and Gattlib error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55530/pybluez-and-gattlib-error)

The steps that give me the error:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib
cd pygattlib
cat DEPENDS

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py35.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py36.so

sudo python3 setup.py install
```

The error I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python36
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems I do have libboost_python installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pygattlib $ ldconfig -p | grep libboost_python
        libboost_python-py35.so.1.62.0 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py35.so.1.62.0
        libboost_python-py35.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py35.so
        libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0
        libboost_python-py27.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py27.so
```

What else can I try to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Since this command returned `libboost_python35`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pygattlib $ ldconfig -p | grep libboost_python
        libboost_python-py35.so.1.62.0 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py35.so.1.62.0
        libboost_python-py35.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py35.so
        libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0
        libboost_python-py27.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_python-py27.so
```

In `setup.py` I set `boost_libs` equal to this:

```
boost_libs = ["boost_python-py35"]
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 3):

That happened with my Raspberry Pi 4, I could fix by running below command, 100% worked:

```
sudo apt install pkg-config libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev libbluetooth-dev libglib2.0-dev python-dev
```